# Small question on improper complex integral intuition

Tags: complex-integration

Recently, I am dealing with an integral
$$\int^\infty_{a+bi}f(z)dz$$ where $f(z)$ is a meromorphic function on $\mathbb C$.

The $\infty$ shall be understood as the real positive infinity, and conventionally the integral is along a straight line connecting the two endpoints.

When I draw out the integral path, I got [image]

The path is the hypotenuse of a right angled triangle with an infinitely long base and a finite height. Thus, the slope of the integral path is zero.

So, intuitively,
$$\int^\infty_{a+bi}f(z)dz=\int^{\infty+bi}_{a+bi}f(z)dz$$ and the integral path can be described as $\Im(z)=b, \Re(z)\ge a$.

Is the equality (trivially) true? If yes, how can one prove it mathematically?

Comment: @metamorphy Okay...So I essentially think that no poles can lie within the triangle with vertices $(a,b)$ $(R,0)$ $(R,b)$ where $R\to+\infty$. Is that always true?

Comment: @metamorphy Thank you. Can you provide a proof?